# OpenOffice "line" for asterisks...how to delete the !#$ thing?

Tags: openoffice

Silly question maybe but I'm tired of looking through the options to get rid of it.

In open office, if I add a few **** in a line and hit enter, a bar appears. It seems that I can't turn it off, and I can't seem to delete it without deleting lines above and below it.

Is there a simple way to get rid of it? Right now I'm using the latest OO.o on the Mac but I have it happen on the Linux version as well.

How do you turn this "feature" off?

How do you delete the bar without deleting paragraphs?

Backspacing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The same "feature" occurs in MS Office... Like to know a answer to this question for that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OOO help file (Writer):

> **To Stop Drawing a Line When You Type Three Identical Characters**
>
> OpenOffice.org automatically draws a line when you type three of the
>   following characters and press Enter:
>
> ```
> - _ = * ~ #
> ```
>
> 1. Choose Tools > AutoCorrect Options.
> 2. Click the Options tab.
> 3. Unmark the “Apply border” check box."

Check out "automatic lines/borders in text" for more.

Comment: BORDER? It calls it a BORDER? That's not quite the intuitive fix I thought it would be...thanks, I'll dig into that.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. Never would have thought it was a border. @#%@#

Comment: Hi, I've created a new question on removing such a line from an already saved document that you may be able to answer: http://superuser.com/questions/284879/remove-auto-corrected-line-in-openoffice-org-writer