# Remove "auto-corrected" line (---, ***) in OpenOffice.org Writer

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

[this question](https://superuser.com/questions/164802/openoffice-line-for-asterisks-how-to-delete-the-thing) answers the question on how to stop the line from being autocorrected from ---. I don't have a problem with that. I'm having a problem with a saved document containing such a line that I need to get removed.

I am referring to a line similar to HTML tag <hr>, like this:

---

This line is generated by typing --- and hitting enter. I'm unable to remove such a line from a document in OpenOffice's Writer.

How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try highlighting the page/paragraph and use RightClick (or Format menu), Format, Page/Paragraph, Borders, None.
Alternatively use default format. 
It does seem rather erratic though so you may need to experiment with format either paragraph/page.

Comment: Thanks. I had to repeat the procedure multiple times. Quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it by selecting the paragraph that contained the horizontal line and changing it's format to standard formatting.

- Mouse-click at the start of the paragraph
- Hold mouse-button and then select the section that contains the horizontal line
- Format -> Standard formatting (or STRG + M)

Et voila. The horizontal line(s) dissapear. Good luck!